# How to pass variable values to a script and run it in one line?

Tags: parameter

I have a file (temp_4n.in) with the following lines:

```
 5  C   172.0696  
 5  C   135.6942  
 5  H   30.9062  
 5  H   31.8124  
 12 H   31.0377  
 12 O   293.0612  
 12 H   32.4678
```

I have a script (testsc.txt) that will extract the last H for the lines starting with a certain number which I will change regularly:

```
 grep $'^${mold}\tH' temp_4n.in | tail -1 > temp_5n.in
```

However, when I run the script (wanting, for example, the line starting with 12) using the following command, it fails:

```
 qsub -v mold=12 ./testsc.txt
```

I think this has something to do with the first '$' in the grep command being regarded as a parameter and erroneously being substituted. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qsub -v varname=value` sets `varname` to the `value` provided in the environment of the job submitted.

In the script that you submit, you use this value in a `grep` command, but the string that contains the variable is quoted with single quotes, preventing the shell from expanding it.

Your script should instead be using

```
grep "^$mold[[:blank:]]H" temp_4n.in | tail -1 > temp_5n.in
```

The initial `$` in your code (`$'...'`) is not needed here and instead we use `[[:blank:]]` to match a space or tab.

---

An alternative would be to use `awk` in your script:

```
awk -v mold="$mold" '$1 == mold && $2 == "H" { this = $0 } END { print this }' temp_4n.in >temp_5n.in
```

This uses string comparisons (not regular expressions) to test the first and second column, and when a matching line is found the whole line is saved in the variable `this`.  At the end, the last value of `this` is printed.  This replaces both of `grep` and `tail`.